# How to trigger a WK Notification

Tags: swift, xcode, notifications, watch

What code do I write to trigger a watch kit notification from the watch app itself? For example, if I connect a button from my watch storyboard to my WatchInterfaceController as an action then when pressed it triggers a notification on the watch.

Answer (score 1):

For trigger a notification, first of all you need permission: (declared usually in the ExtensionDelegate)

```
func askPermission() {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert,.sound]) { (authBool, error) in
        if authBool {
            let okAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ok", title: "Ok", options: [])
            let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "exampleCategoryIdentifier", actions: [okAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

For having this working, you need to import (in the ExtensionDelegate) "UserNotifications" and to extend:

> UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Once you have done that, you can call askPermission where you want, in a way like this:

```
    if let delegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as? ExtensionDelegate {
        delegate.askPermission()
    }
```

Now you have (hopefully) the permission for trigger a notification! 
For trigger a notification, you can use a function like this:

```
func notification() {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = "Body Of The Notification"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "exampleCategoryIdentifier" // Re-Use the same identifier of the previous category.
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default() // This is optional

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: NSUUID().uuidString,
                                        content: content,
                                        trigger: nil)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            print("notification: ok")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Please consider taking a "glance" (lol) at my unanswered questions too. Incase you could help me out!

Answer (score 0):

In order to test watch notifications, you must first create a new build scheme.

Duplicate your watch app scheme, and in the "Run" section, choose your custom notification as the executable.

Now you can run the notification scheme.

Inside the extensions group in your project, under Supporting Files is a file called PushNotificationPayload.json.

You can edit the payload file to try different notifications and categories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in terms of calling a notification in normal circumstances (on a real device not associated with Xcode) what code must I use for it to be triggered?

Comment: That's not possible. You should use a remote notification provider like Pusher (which is quite easy to implement). So when you go to their web interface and send a Push notification it'll appear on all 'subscribed' devices. But it's not possible to trigger it with a button or anything like that.